# Is there something similar to named pipe transport for wcf in IIS6?

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis

I have a web service that will only be called from the same box.  In IIS 7 I have used named pipe endpoints for security and speed.  the project I am working on now has the same requirements but will be on server 2003 IIS 6.  What are my options to restrict access to only the local machine?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS6 only supports http and wshttp protocols.  You could run your WCF in a Windows Service and control everything as you do now (however that may be).  There are tons of ways to secure it as well.

Self Signed certificates between the two (popular over the internet)

Windows Authentication and control list (easy on same network/domain)

UserName Password (also easy).

But if you have it working now, I would attempt to rehost into a Windows Service, which should not take away your current functionality.

You should know by the way that if use named pipes over a network, it is actually just remoting via TCP.